# Track all variable state in flask application

Tags: flask

I am attempting to track all variables inside an API request in my Flask application. My goal is to monitor both the previous and current states of these variables.

I've written the following code, but it doesn't seem to be functioning as expected. Can anyone suggest an alternative method to achieve the same result, perhaps using locals() or any other available method?

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from functools import wraps

app = Flask(__name__)

def track_changes(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        # Initial values dictionary
        initial_values = {k: v for k, v in locals().items() if k not in ['func', 'request', 'response']}

        result = func(*args, **kwargs)

        # Final values dictionary
        final_values = {k: v for k, v in locals().items() if k not in ['func', 'request', 'response']}

        # Identify and log changes
        changes = {k: (v1, v2) for k, (v1, v2) in zip(initial_values.keys(), zip(initial_values.values(), final_values.values())) if v1 != v2}

        print ("initial values==>", initial_values)
        print ("final values", final_values)
        if changes:
            print(f"Function: {func.__name__}")
            print("Changes:", changes)

        return result

    return wrapper


@app.route('/hello', methods=['GET'])
@track_changes
def hello():
# Modify value based on request data
    initial_value = 10  # Assuming a default initial value
    new_value = initial_value + 1
    initial_value = 20
    new_value = initial_value

    # Log changes without explicitly creating a class instance
    print(f"Initial value: {initial_value}, New value: {new_value}")
    return jsonify({'message': 'Hello, World!'})

# ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies in how you are tracking the changes. As per your code  in `track_changes` , the scope of function is totally different from where you have defined your variable.

One way to solve this is to use wrapper class which keeps track of state changes and your updated code will look like this :

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from functools import wraps

app = Flask(__name__)

class StateTracker:
    def __init__(self):
        self.state = {}

    def track_changes(self, func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            initial_state = self.get_current_state()
            result = func(*args, **kwargs)
            final_state = self.get_current_state()

            changes = {key: (initial_state[key], final_state[key]) for key in initial_state if initial_state[key] != final_state[key]}
            
            if changes:
                print(f"Function: {func.__name__}")
                print("Changes:", changes)

            return result

        return wrapper

    def get_current_state(self):
        return {key: value for key, value in globals().items() if key not in {'__name__', '__doc__', '__package__', '__loader__', '__spec__'}}

state_tracker = StateTracker()

@app.route('/hello', methods=['GET'])
@state_tracker.track_changes
def hello():
    initial_value = 10
    new_value = initial_value + 1
    initial_value = 20
    new_value = initial_value

    print(f"Initial value: {initial_value}, New value: {new_value}")
    return jsonify({'message': 'Hello, World!'})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Please let me know if you need further help.

Comment: This code also behaves the same. It's not tracking any variables inside the hello method. The problem with the approach, as I see it (existing and current), is that when we call the decorator before the function, those variables aren't available. However, after execution, the variables are present.